# Listing payments on subaddresses

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

How can I continuously monitor payments sent to my subaddresses? I'm aware of `incoming_transfers` RPC call but I would prefer a call that allows me to filter by block height (or something else) so I don't receive old payments which are already processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [get_transfers](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#get_transfers). It has the necessary options to filter by height.